# Probability that a stochastic flow is near $0$

Tags: pr.probability, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-differential-equations

Fix $\epsilon>0$ and let $(\Omega,F,F_t\mathbb{P})$ be a stochastic base.  Is there a (Markov) diffusion process $X_t$ satisfying an SDE of the form:
$$
d X_t = \mu(t,X_t)dt + \Sigma(t,X_t)dW_t, X_0^x
$$
such that the (random) function $f_X:x\to X_1^x$ satisfies 
$$
\mathbb{P}\left(
\int_{x \in \mathbb{R}^n} |f_X(x)| dx < \epsilon
\right)=1?
$$
If not, can we estimate the probability that this holds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\newcommand\ep\epsilon$  $\newcommand\R{\mathbb R}$ $\newcommand\Si{\Sigma}$ 
Let 
$$X^x_t:=xe^{-ct|x|}$$
for some real $c>0$ and allreal $t\ge0$ and $x\in\R^n$. Then $X^x_0=x$ for all $x$ and 
your SDE holds with $\mu(t,x)=-c|x|xe^{-ct|x|}$ and $\Si(t,x)=0$. Moreover,
$$\int_{\R^n}|X^x_1|\,dx=\int_{\R^n}|x|e^{-c|x|}\,dx<\ep,$$
as desired, if $c=c_\ep$ is large enough.

---

If you insist on $\Si(t,x)\ne0$, you can clearly make $P(\int_{\R^n}|X^x_1|\,dx<\ep)$ arbitrarily close to $1$, by approximation.

Comment: But I'm a bit confused.  So in general, for a typical function we would take $X_t^x = x(e^{-ct|x|} +f(x))$?

Comment: The current version of your question is completely different from the original one. I suggest you restore the original question and post any other questions you may have separately.

Comment: Fair enough, I have rolled-back the question and posted the modified one here: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/362274/large-deviations-estimate-for-arbitrary-continuous-function