# Large deviations estimate for arbitrary continuous function

Tags: pr.probability, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-differential-equations, large-deviations

Fix $\epsilon>0$ and let $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mathcal{F}_t,\mathbb{P})$ be a stochastic base, and let $f:\mathbb{R}^n\to \mathbb{R}^n$ be a continous function with $f(0)=0$.  Is there a family of Markov diffusion processse $X_t^{x,\epsilon}$ satisfying an SDE of the form:
$$
\begin{cases}
d X_t^{x,\epsilon} = \mu(t,X_t^{x,\epsilon},\epsilon)dt + \Sigma(t,X_t^{x,\epsilon},\epsilon)dW_t
\\
X_0^{x,\epsilon}=f(x)
\end{cases}
$$
and such that $
\mathbb{P}\left(
\sup_{t \in [0,1],x \in \mathbb{R}^n}|X_t^{x,\epsilon} - f(x)| < \epsilon
\right)
$
holds with high probability?

Note: Of course, here, we require that $\Sigma(t,x,\epsilon)>0$ to avoid trivial solutions.

Comment: I think Freidlin-Wentzell theory can be used but I'm not sure it will give you a positive probability...

Comment: What is your initial condition for $X^{x,\epsilon}$? Is it $x$? Then $f$ must go from $\mathbb R^n$ to itself, right?

Comment: You have $x$ under the probability sign. What is the quantifier on $x$ there?

Comment: The supremum should be over both t and x.

Comment: If the initial condition is $x$, and $f(x)\neq x$, then $X^{x,\epsilon}$ cannot be close to $f(x)$ for $t$ small.

Comment: True, I have fixed this.  Thank you Pierre.

Comment: What about letting $X_t^{x,\epsilon}:=f(x)$ for all $t,x$ (with $\mu=0$), and then modifying $X$ by choosing $\Sigma>0$ to be arbitrarily small?

Comment: Yes I'm noting this now... and I think this also has the property that $X_t^{x,\epsilon}$ can be close to any other function with positive probability, which is nice.